# Resultset movement to first record

Tags: java, android

I have following code:

```
try
        {
            rsEjamatData=con.getLiveEjamatPass(ejmtid);

            List<Mikats> dbmessages = mdb.getAllMikats();

            for (Mikats c:dbmessages){

            if(rsEjamatData.next())
            {
                if(rsEjamatData.getInt(rsEjamatData.findColumn("AutoID"))!=c.getAutoID())
                {
                    flag=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag=2;
                }

            }
            }


            if(flag==0 || flag==1)
            {
                rsEjamatData.last();
                rsEjamatData.beforeFirst();
            }



            //flag=1;

            //if(rsData.next() )
            {
            if(flag==0 || flag==1 || rsEjamatData.getRow()>dbmessages.size())
            {

            while(rsEjamatData.next())
            {
                String eJamatID = rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("eJamatID"));
                String mktid = rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("MikatID"));
                String StartDate = rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("StartDate"));                             
                String EndDate=rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("EndDate"));

                String Block = rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("Block"));
                String Floor = rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("Floor"));
                String gate = rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("gate"));                             
                String masjid=rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("masjid"));

                String AutoID = rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("AutoID"));                             
                String SeatName=rsEjamatData.getString(rsEjamatData.findColumn("SeatName"));

                cnt++;
                mdb.addEjamatPass(new Mikats(Integer.parseInt(eJamatID),Integer.parseInt(mktid), StartDate, EndDate, Block,Floor,gate,masjid, Integer.parseInt( AutoID),SeatName),cnt);


            }
            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In this code when i make :

```
for (Mikats c:dbmessages){

            if(rsEjamatData.next())
```

Resultset moves in forword direction.

After this process happened, i wanted to have my resultset back to first position.

So i written:

```
if(flag==0 || flag==1)
            {
                rsEjamatData.last();
                rsEjamatData.beforeFirst();
            }
```

But when code comes in `rsEjamatData.last();` It gives me following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet may only be accessed in a forward direction.
```

I also tried directly writting `rsEjamatData.first()` , but given me same error.

Please guid me.

Without comming on first position, it does not enters into

```
while(rsEjamatData.next())
            {

................
................

}
```

So plz help me.

Comment: Can you just try adding rsEjamatData.beforeFirst();

Comment: @VKSingla wait i will try it

Comment: @VKSingla same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a Scrollable ResultSet . Eg.

// Create a scrollable result set

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

// Move cursor to the beginning, before the first row.
    // cursor position is 0.

```
   resultSet.beforeFirst();
```

Comment: @henriqueor Please post a separate answer instead of editing this one.

Comment: In this case is there any drawback ? Like why does the default resultset not scrollable ?